# Tool to reduce a partition's size and create a new one from the command-line

Tags: partition, parted

At the moment I don't have any free space:

```
(parted) mkpart 
Partition type? primary/extended? primary 
File system type? [ext2]? ext4 
Start? 60G
End? 62.9G
Warning: You requested a partition from 60.0GB to 62.9GB. 
The closest location we can manage is 250GB to 250GB.

Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number Start End Size Type File system Flags
1 2097kB 62.9GB 62.9GB primary ntfs
2 62.9GB 63.4GB 524MB primary ext4
3 63.4GB 250GB 187GB primary boot, lvm
```

I want to reduce the size of an NTFS partition (1) so I can make a new one. I need a console tool like `parted`, not a GUI like `gparted`.

Comment: try `ntfsresize`,see http://linuxtechres.blogspot.in/2007/08/how-to-use-ntfsresize-from-command-line.html for instructions. hope this helps :)